# Reforming movement timetable. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

By executing the following query (I'm using `Oracle 11g`)

```
SELECT EVENTARCHIVE.VEHID vehicle
      , to_char(EVENTARCHIVE.EVENTTIME, 'Dy DD-Mon-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS') occured_on
      , EVENTARCHIVE.EVENTDESCR description
FROM EVENTARCHIVE
     , (SELECT POX
               , POY
               , AREARAD 
        FROM POINTOBJECTS
        WHERE POID = 'PB') PO
WHERE POWER(X - PO.POX, 2) + POWER(Y - PO.POY, 2) < POWER(PO.AREARAD, 2) 
AND   EVENTARCHIVE.EVENTGROUP = 2
```

I'm getting a dataset like this

```
vehicle | occred_on   | description
017     | .. 08:35:12 | stopped moving
021     | .. 09:40:00 | stopped moving
021     | .. 10:00:00 | started moving
```

As you can see there are two statuses for the 21th vehicle revealing its stoppage time. The stoppage was 20 minutes long. This is minimal span between `stop.mv` and `started.mv` flags.

I want to reform it accordingly to this

```
vehicle | stopped_moving | started_moving
021     | .. 09:40:00    | .. 10:00:00
```

How do I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: How many instances of STOP.MV and START.MV are there per vehicle?  Can you have a START.MV before a STOP.MV in your data set?  (Because obviously that's what happens in real life).

Comment: There are many such spans per single vehicle, you are right. For the given single span it is important to find the nearest point in time (with flag `start.mv`) that would end it up.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve a result like "started moving" -> "stopped again" if the interval is small enough? Or is it only "stopped" -> "started again"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this perhaps?

```
SQL> create table EVENTARCHIVE ( VEHID number, EVENTTIME date, EVENTDESCR  varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> REM vehice 17 has no started moving record.
SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(17, to_date('24/12/2012 08:35:12', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'stopped moving');

1 row created.

SQL> REM vehice 21 has multiple stop / starts
SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(21, to_date('24/12/2012 09:40:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'stopped moving');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(21, to_date('24/12/2012 10:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'started moving');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(21, to_date('24/12/2012 10:22:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'stopped moving');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(21, to_date('24/12/2012 12:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'started moving');

1 row created.

SQL> REM vehice 25 has multiple stop / starts records start with a started moving record.
SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(25, to_date('23/12/2012 16:35:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'started moving');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(25, to_date('23/12/2012 22:59:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'stopped moving');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(25, to_date('24/12/2012 07:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'started moving');

1 row created.

SQL> REM vehice 33 has some duplicate stopped data (possible?)
SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(33, to_date('23/12/2012 16:35:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'started moving');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(33, to_date('23/12/2012 22:59:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'stopped moving');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(33, to_date('23/12/2012 23:02:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'stopped moving');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into EVENTARCHIVE values(33, to_date('24/12/2012 07:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'started moving');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select vehid, eventtime stopped_moving, next_time started_moving
  2    from (select vehid, eventtime, eventdescr,
  3         case
  4           when lead(eventdescr) over (partition by vehid order by eventtime) != eventdescr
  5           then
  6             lead(eventtime)  over (partition by vehid order by eventtime)
  7         end next_time
  8  from EVENTARCHIVE)
  9   where eventdescr = 'stopped moving'
 10     and next_time is not null;

     VEHID STOPPED_MOVING       STARTED_MOVING
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        21 24-dec-2012 09:40:00 24-dec-2012 10:00:00
        21 24-dec-2012 10:22:00 24-dec-2012 12:00:00
        25 23-dec-2012 22:59:00 24-dec-2012 07:00:00
        33 23-dec-2012 23:02:00 24-dec-2012 07:00:00
```

Comment: That's really great query! I was thinking about using self join but I wouldn't write it so cool!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a subquery, maybe something like that works:

```
SELECT 
    e1.VEHID vehicle, 
    to_char(e1.EVENTTIME, 'Dy DD-Mon-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS') stopped, 
    to_char(e2.EVENTTIME, 'Dy DD-Mon-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS') started 
FROM 
    EVENTARCHIVE e1, 
    EVENTARCHIVE e2 
WHERE 
    e1.EVENTDESCR = 'stopped moving' 
    AND e2.ID IN (
        SELECT ID 
        FROM EVENTARCHIVE 
        WHERE 
            EVENTTIME<e1.EVENTTIME 
            AND EVENTDESCR = 'started moving' 
            AND VEHID = e1.VEHID 
        ORDER BY e1.EVENTTIME DESC LIMIT 1
    )
```

(I assumed there is a column `ID`.)
This should also work with multiple stopped/started entries for a vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
select min(occred_on) stopped_moving,max(occred_on) started_moving
from table group by vehicle;
```

Hope this will help,

```
SELECT EVENTARCHIVE.VEHID vehicle
      , min(to_char(EVENTARCHIVE.EVENTTIME, 'Dy DD-Mon-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS')) stopped_moving,
        max(to_char(EVENTARCHIVE.EVENTTIME, 'Dy DD-Mon-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS')) started_moving,
      , EVENTARCHIVE.EVENTDESCR description
FROM EVENTARCHIVE
     , (SELECT POX
               , POY
               , AREARAD 
        FROM POINTOBJECTS
        WHERE POID = 'PB') PO
WHERE POWER(X - PO.POX, 2) + POWER(Y - PO.POY, 2) < POWER(PO.AREARAD, 2) 
AND   EVENTARCHIVE.EVENTGROUP = 2 group by vehicle
```

Comment: This is "correct" as far as the posted requirement but is unlikely to be helpful to the OP's actual situation.  However, they provide us with all the details of their table structures and data they won't get a better answer.

Comment: yeah @APC. We are not sure of what is happening in their environment right? If the user provide more details then we can give more precise solutions!! Thanks for your feedback!!

Comment: min and max won't do the thing. I'll expand my question.